# Angular 8 como pasar un id por url a un componente

Tags: json, angular, api

Estoy haciendo una prueba con angular 8 y necesito pasar un id por url a un componente.

Tengo un componente llamado playlist el cual me pinta un nombre y un avatar. Utilizo **json server** para simular un api.

Tengo un directorio llamado api en el cual tengo un archivo **db.json** con el siguiente array de objetos playlist:

```
{
  "playlists": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Playlist test 1",
      "avatar": "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Playlist test 2",
      "avatar": "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Playlist test 3",
      "avatar": "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Dentro del directorio api también tengo un archivo **routes.json**:

```
{
  "/api/*": "/$1"
}
```

En el archivo **`app-routing.module`** tengo el siguiente array de rutas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',component:HomeComponent },
  { path: 'item', component: ItemComponent },
  { path: 'playlist', component: PlayListComponent },
  { path: 'playlist/:id', component: PlayListComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

En cuanto al componente playlist en su archivo **.ts** tengo el siguiente código:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-list',
  templateUrl: './play-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./play-list.component.scss']
})
export class PlayListComponent implements OnInit {

  // teams$ = this.http.get('/ api / teams');
  playlists$: Observable<any> = this.http.get('/api/playlists');
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}
```

En el **.html** del playlist tengo:

```
<div *ngFor="let playlist of playlists$ | async" class="top-info">
  <div *ngIf="playlist.id == 1">
    <img src="{{playlist.avatar}}" alt="avatar" class="img-avatar" />
    <p>{{ playlist.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="options">
  <p>TENDENCIAS</p>
  <P>MIS SUSCRIPCIONES</P>
  <P>FAVORITOS</P>
  <P>RELACIONES</P>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Tal y como lo tengo ahora, para mostrar los diferentes objetos playlist del **`db.json`** tengo que modificarlos manualmente en el .html del componente playlist poniendo:

```
playlist.id == 1
playlist.id == 2
playlist.id == 3
```

De esta forma me pinta el nombre y avatar del objeto 1, 2 o 3.

[image: componente playlist]

Lo que necesito es poder cargarle al componente playlist los distinto objetos por medio de la url, por ejemplo:

> http://localhost:4200/playlist/1
> http://localhost:4200/playlist/2
> http://localhost:4200/playlist/3

No doy con la forma adecuada de hacerlo. ¿Alguien hizo algo similar?

Gracias de antemano, un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes recibir el dato de la url utilizando [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute) según la documentación puedes ver lo que dice:

> Provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet

---

> **Traducción:**
> Proporciona acceso a información sobre una ruta asociada a un componente que se carga en una toma de corriente

Básicamente, en el objeto de tipo *AtivatedRoute* tenemos observables que nos sirven para suscribirnos a cambios en los parámetros enviados al componente.

Veamos un ejemplo, en el método ngOnInit agregamos lo siguiente:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
  console.log('Esto recibo desde url:', params.get('id'));
});
```

Como puedes ver si la url es **`http://localhost:4200/playlist/2`** en la consola deberías ver:

> Esto recibo desde url: 2

Expliquemos un poco: Accedemos a la propiedad *paramMap*, esto porque paramMap detectará el cambio *"incluso cuando se realiza en el mismo componente"*, y posteriormente mostramos en consola el id que pasaste por url, en este caso si te fijas uso el nombre del parámetro que pusiste en tus rutas **`path: 'playlist/:id'`** de la siguiente forma `params.get('id')`.

Ahora según tu lógica **"la cual no voy a corregir en este caso"** iteras en el *HTML* comparando los id de los objetos y así mostrar el que ingresó por url, continuando con lo que ya hiciste la forma más sencilla que veo es usar una variable *id* que se igualará con el parámetro recibido por url como se ve a continuación.

```
public idPlaylist; // id ingresado por url
```

Y en el observable donde mostrábamos el mensaje en consola lo corregimos:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
  this.idPlaylist = params.get('id');
});
```

Quedando tu typescript de la siguiente forma:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-list',
  templateUrl: './play-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./play-list.component.scss']
})
export class PlayListComponent implements OnInit {

  // teams$ = this.http.get('/ api / teams');
  playlists$: Observable<any> = this.http.get('/api/playlists');
  public idPlaylist; // id ingresado por url
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.idPlaylist = params.get('id');
    });
  }
}
```

Finalmente nos vamos al *HTML* y reemplazamos el id que utilizabas por la variable *idPlaylist*:

```
<div *ngFor="let playlist of playlists$ | async" class="top-info">
  <div *ngIf="playlist.id == idPlaylist"> <!-- Aquí va el id recibido por url -->
    <img src="{{playlist.avatar}}" alt="avatar" class="img-avatar" />
    <p>{{ playlist.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma deberías poder cambiar entre playlist según cambies la url manualmente o por medio de un link.